# How do I access a user's instance of iTunes using WScript run as SYSTEM user?

Tags: javascript, com, itunes, wsh

I am trying to use JavaScript and the iTunes COM interface to add files to my iTunes library. I have written a JavaScript file that successfully adds a file to my library, but *only when called from the command line.*

When I run the same script from a browser, it creates an iTunes application as the SYSTEM user, and this is where I believe my problem lies...

So what I'm trying to accomplish is to access either the iTunes instance running under my user as opposed to SYSTEM user, or to add my user's iTunes library instead of the SYSTEM user's library.

Here is the JavaScript:

```
var iTunesApp = WScript.CreateObject("iTunes.Application"); 

iTunesApp.LibraryPlaylist.AddFile('B:\\filetoadd.mp4');
```

Comment: WScript is evil. Don't run that in the browser. Get the user to run something better like a perl script. or an exe.

Answer (score 0):

Windows scripting host is not really flexible enough to do this, so you would have to come up with some sort of hack:

- Create a symlink from %windir%\system32\config\systemprofile\?path to itunes library? to your users library (iTunes is probably not designed to handle this and so it might not work or could break stuff)
- Since you are running as SYSTEM you have a lot of power, you could schedule a task that runs your script with a special parameter as yourself and then control iTunes

Comment: The script is being run from a mobile browser. The idea is to have a webapp on a mobile device. The webapp can initiate the reencoding of a downloaded file. The last step in the process is to add the new file to iTunes. So the JavaScript is being called by the webapp running in a browser. So the script is being run as SYSTEM and thus not connecting with the user's instance of iTunes.

Comment: I don't really understand, if it is running in a browser, why is the browser running as SYSTEM?

Comment: You are correct, I had confused myself while trying different things. One of my attempts was the following:
`$WshShell = new COM("WScript.Shell"); $oExec = $WshShell->Run("CScript.exe \"C:/pathtojavascript/addfile.js\"", 0, false);`
This code would run the JavaScript as SYSTEM due to the webserver being run as the SYSTEM user.
 My question now is then, if the JavaScript successfully adds the file to the iTunes library when run from command line, why doesn't a call to the javascript from the browser work?